# Session attribute value is returing as null during load testing

Tags: java, jsp, session

I have a scenario. I am working on a web application that is using the servlet/JSP technology and deployed in tomcat server.

There is a page named `loginServlet`.
I have set a session attribute in `loginServlet` named `userRole`.

It's working fine but when load increases during load testing, the session attribute (`userRole`) is returning null.

How to resolve this?

Comment: are you sure you are passing sesion id everytime ? (cookies/in url)

Comment: I am creating session Object before login, It's working fine. Whenever load increase to 200-300 at the same time, 5-10 user is not able to get the session attribute value that is set at the time of login.

Comment: I guess it fails load testing.

Comment: No It's not fault of Load Testing, because at the time of Load Testing some user also doing manual Testing and they are facing same problem.